# How do I get kint() to include the variable name in output?

Tags: 8, debugging

My understanding that normally kint will display the variable name in the output, e.g. `$abc`. But in my code `kint($abc)` never outputs the `$abc` label so when I have multiple `kint`s it becomes very confusing. Any idea how to force this or label kint output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the variables in an array. Then you see the variable names and you have the advantage, that if the first variable is a big array you can collapse it to see the second one:

```
kint(array(
  'abc' => $abc,
  'def' => $def,  
));
```